# Removing spot color before printing causes white (cut) space underneath

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, color, export

Help pretty please. I have an *.ai for printing where spot (100% magenta) color marks die. Die color (as layer) is deleted just before printing, after adjusting position in printer. Data are prepared in illustrator, then placed in Indesign and exported to pdf.

I've recently upgraded my computer, reinstalled everything and for some reason, somewhere in the process, something went wrong.
Deleting spot color from exported pdf now causes cut/blank space in image.

It might be just trivial setting in Indesign export, but I couldn't figure it out.

[image: example]

Comment: Are you printing in home? in an ink jet printer?

Answer (score 3):

The cutter guide needs to be set to OVERPRINT (it is currently knocking out). To do this in Illustrator or InDesign, you need to select the cutter guide lines, open the ATTRIBUTES palette and then check the box next to Overprint Stroke. Then re-export your PDF and all should be well.